# Sonar cognitive complexity checking for a function

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I try to understand how sonarqube calculates the coginitive complexity and I wonder if this is correct and for instance this function's complexity is indeed 16. I guess it is not 16 because limit of 15 was not exceeded. Can you help me what is exact cognitive complexity of this function?
Thank you.

```
bool sonarQuestion()
{
    if (not (1 and 0 and 1))  // 1 + 2 (1 for if + 2 logical operators) = 3
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (1 and 1) // 1 + 1 = 2 
    {
        if (not (1 and 2 and 3 and (1 or 0))) // 1 + 4 + 1 (1 for if + 4 logical operator + 1 for nesting) = 6
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (2) // 1 
    {
        if (not (2 and 3 and 5)) // 1 + 2 + 1 = 4 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // total is 16
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting way of looking at complexity. I'm not familiar with Sonar at all, but I did find [this link](https://assets-eu-01.kc-usercontent.com/520ec90f-36f8-0183-9f21-e10334942471/e89714ed-2e5b-4119-9ff7-3ccdef359ee9/CognitiveComplexity.pdf) where they explain the principles. Looking at that document, I *think* your example has a score of 12:

```
bool sonarQuestion()
{
    // 1 + 1 (1 if, 1 sequence of operators)
    if (not (1 and 0 and 1))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (1 and 1) // +1 +1
    {
        // +2 +2 (nested if, 2 sequences)
        if (not (1 and 2 and 3 and (1 or 0))) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (2) // +1 
    {
        if (not (2 and 3 and 5)) // +2 +1
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // total is 2 + 6 + 4 = 12
    return true;
}
```